# Unable to Analyse data

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-flink

val patterns = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternStateDescriptor)

The imports I made

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{MapStateDescriptor, ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.Types
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.BroadcastStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer010
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector
```

Here's the code

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  val properties = new Properties()
  properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")

  val patternStream = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010("patterns", new SimpleStringSchema, properties)

  val patterns = env.addSource(patternStream)

  var patternData = patterns.map {
    str =>
      val splitted_str = str.split(",")
      PatternStream(splitted_str(0).trim, splitted_str(1).trim, splitted_str(2).trim)
  }

  val logsStream = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010("logs", new SimpleStringSchema, properties)

//  logsStream.setStartFromEarliest()

  val logs = env.addSource(logsStream)

  var data = logs.map {
    str =>
      val splitted_str = str.split(",")
      LogsTest(splitted_str.head.trim, splitted_str(1).trim, splitted_str(2).trim)
  }

  val keyedData: KeyedStream[LogsTest, String] = data.keyBy(_.metric)

  val bcStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor[Unit, PatternStream]("patterns", Types.UNIT, Types.of[PatternStream]) // first type defined is for the key and second data type defined is for the value

  val broadcastPatterns: BroadcastStream[PatternStream]  = patternData.broadcast(bcStateDescriptor)

  val alerts = keyedData
      .connect(broadcastPatterns)
      .process(new PatternEvaluator())

  alerts.print()

//   println(alerts.getClass)
//  val sinkProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer010("output",  new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)



  env.execute("Flink Broadcast State Job")
}

class PatternEvaluator()
  extends KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, LogsTest, PatternStream, (String, String, String)] {

  private lazy val patternStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor("patterns", classOf[String], classOf[String])

  private var lastMetricState: ValueState[String] = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    val lastMetricDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor("last-metric", classOf[String])

    lastMetricState = getRuntimeContext.getState(lastMetricDescriptor)
  }

  override def processElement(reading: LogsTest,
                              readOnlyCtx: KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, LogsTest, PatternStream, (String, String, String)]#ReadOnlyContext,
                              out: Collector[(String, String, String)]): Unit = {

    val metrics = readOnlyCtx.getBroadcastState(patternStateDescriptor)
    if (metrics.contains(reading.metric)) {
      val metricPattern: String = metrics.get(reading.metric)
      val metricPatternValue: String = metrics.get(reading.value)
      val lastMetric = lastMetricState.value()

      val logsMetric = (reading.metric)
      val logsValue = (reading.value)


      if (logsMetric == metricPattern) {
        if (metricPatternValue == logsValue) {
          out.collect((reading.timestamp, reading.value, reading.metric))
        }
      }
    }
  }


  override def processBroadcastElement(
                                        update: PatternStream,
                                        ctx: KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction[String, LogsTest, PatternStream, (String, String, String)]#Context,
                                        out: Collector[(String, String, String)]
                                      ): Unit = {
    val patterns = ctx.getBroadcastState(patternStateDescriptor)

    if (update.metric == "IP") {
      patterns.put(update.metric /*,update.operator*/ , update.value)
    }
    //    else if (update.metric == "username"){
    //      patterns.put(update.metric, update.value)
    //    }
    //    else {
    //      println("No required data found")
    //    }
    //  }

  }
}
```

Sample Data :- Logs Stream

```
"21/09/98","IP", "5.5.5.5"
```

Pattern Stream

```
"IP","==","5.5.5.5"
```

I'm unable to analyse data by getting desired result, i.e = 21/09/98,IP,5.5.5.5

There's no error as of now, it's just not analysing the data

The code is reading streams (Checked)

Comment: Yes, seeing the code would help a lot. If you want to look at a working example, see https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_scala/broadcast/NearestTaxiSolution.scala

Comment: @DavidAnderson Kindly check it now. It would mean alot if you could help

Comment: @DavidAnderson there's an error, it says process is still overloaded

Comment: Please either edit this question to provide clear information about this new problem -- or ask a new question.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Check the code now

Comment: You keep changing the question, each time rendering my previous answer useless, as it no longer responds to anything in the question. Stack Overflow isn't a forum for iterative debugging -- it's a place to collect answers to questions that others can learn from.

Comment: Sorry @DavidAnderson I'll keep note of that

Answer (score 0):

One common source of trouble in cases like this is that the API offers no control over the order in which the patterns and the data are ingested. It could be that processElement is being called before processBroadcastElement.